# Polymorphic associations break in rails 6.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I have inherited some legacy rails code with workarounds around standard polymorphic associations. These used to work up until rails 5. Now I am trying to upgrade to rails6.1 and they break and I have no clue as to how to fix them.

**Problem:**
We have following 2 tables:

1. posts

   - id
   - text
   - ...
2. comments

   - id
   - commentable_id
   - commentable_type
   - ...

A post has 3 types of comments -

1. Admin comment
2. Anonymous comment
3. User comment

We have modeled this as polymorphic relationship as follows:

```
# comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

```
# post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as :commentable, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :post

  has_many :admin_comments, -> { where commentable_type: "AdminComment" },
    class_name: 'Comment', foreign_key: :commentable_id,
    foreign_type: :commentable_type, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :post

  has_many :user_comments, -> { where commentable_type: "UserComment" },
    class_name: 'Comment', foreign_key: :commentable_id,
    foreign_type: :commentable_type, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :post

  has_many :anonymous_comments, -> { where commentable_type: "AnonymousComment" },
    class_name: 'Comment', foreign_key: :commentable_id,
    foreign_type: :commentable_type, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :post
end
```

With this setup, I could fetch either all comments by doing -

```
p = Post.find(123)
p.comments
```

or fetch comments by specific type of user -

```
p = Post.find(123)
p.user_comments
p.anonymous_comments
```

With rails 6.1 this setup does not work.
When trying to run `rails console` It fails with error:

> ruby2.7.x/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:52:in `block in assert_valid_keys': Unknown key: :foreign_type. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :primary_key, :foreign_key, :dependent, :validate, :inverse_of, :strict_loading, :autosave, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :counter_cache, :join_table, :index_errors, :ensuring_owner_was (ArgumentError)

After looking for potential answers online, the closest I could get was by adding `as: :commentable` to each association like -

```
  has_many :user_comments, -> { where commentable_type: "UserComment" },
    class_name: 'Comment', foreign_key: :commentable_id,
    foreign_type: :commentable_type, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :post, as: :commentable
```

But this does not get me correct result set. It generates sql as follows -

> SELECT comments.* FROM comments WHERE comments.commentable_id = 123 AND comments.commentable_type = 'Post' AND comments.commentable_type = 'UserComment'

without `as: :commentable` it would generate sql as -

> SELECT comments.* FROM comments WHERE comments.commentable_id = 123  AND comments.commentable_type = 'UserComment'

I am kinda lost and would appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `source` ? You should not have to write that much. Is there a reason you're not using `as` key word? 

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an extremely confused and misguided attempt at a combination of  Single Table Inheritance and a polymorphic assocations with no understanding of how either works and I doubt the code actually worked as intended in earlier versions.

### STI

In a STI setup you use the type inheritance column (type by default) to specify what class ActiveRecord will load by when retrieving the rows from the database. That means your `comments` table should have a string column named `type` containing values such as `UserComment` and `AdminComment`.

```ruby
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end

class UserComment < Comment 
end

class AdminComment < Comment 
end

# ...
```

When you setup a has many assocation pointing to a STI model you should set the condition on the `type` column of the table - not `commentable_type`:

```ruby
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :user_comments, -> { where(type: 'UserComment') }    
  has_many :admin_comments, -> { where(type: 'AdminComment') }
  # ...
end
```

```
irb(main):002:0> puts Post.joins(:user_comments).to_sql
```

```sql
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" 
INNER JOIN "comments" 
ON "comments"."type" = 'UserComment' 
AND "comments"."post_id" = "posts"."id"
```

### Polymorhic assocations

Polymorphic assocations are really just a dirty cheat to get around the Object Relational Impedience Missmatch problem. By using a integer column together with a varchar column you can create a single assocation that points to any table - this would be for example attaching comments to posts, videos, images or even other comments. Thats what the `commentable_type` column should actually be containing.

To change the assocations from the previous example to be polymorphic you just have to add the `as:` option to tell Rails what `belongs_to` assocation to look for:

```ruby
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  has_many :user_comments, 
    -> { where(type: 'UserComment') }, 
    as: :commentable
  has_many :admin_comments, 
    -> { where(type: 'AdminComment') },  
    as: :commentable
end
```

Otherwise it will just assume that you're looking for an assocation named *post* on the other end - and `as:` tells ActiveRecord that its a polymorphic assocation:

```
irb(main):002:0> puts Post.joins(:user_comments).to_sql
```

```sql
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" 
INNER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."commentable_type" = 'Post' 
AND "comments"."type" = 'UserComment' 
AND "comments"."commentable_id" = "posts"."id"
```

You don't have to configure the `foreign_key`, `foreign_type` or `class_name` option (this one was dead wrong) as it all can be derived from the name.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT
After reading the documentation carefully, this should work for `has_one` association types and not `has_many`

Rails 6.1 added [Delegated Types](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/DelegatedType.html) that can be used to achieve what you want.

Try the following

```
# comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

```
# post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as :commentable, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :post
  delegated_type :commentable, types: %w[AdminComment UserComment AnonymousComment], dependent: :destroy
end
```